# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=(\frac{5\sum_{k=1}^nk^4}{n^5})^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find the limit of the following sequence

$x_n=(\frac{5\sum_{k=1}^nk^4}{n^5})^n$

I thought of using the following idea:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{x_n}^{y_n}=e^L\leftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}{y_n({x_n-1})}=L$$

Because the sequence has this form, I had planned to use the definition of the Riemann integral to express the summation in another way, but I cannot find the limit.
Any help please?

Comment: Hint: $\sum^n_{k=1} k^4 = 1/30 n (n + 1) (2 n + 1) (3 n^2 + 3 n - 1)$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula gives formula for numerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\sum^n_{k=1} k^4 = \frac{n (n + 1) (2 n + 1) (3 n^2 + 3 n - 1)}{30}$
whence
$$
\Big( \frac5{n^5}\sum^n_{k=1} k^4\Big)^n=\Big(1+\frac1n\Big)^n\Big(1+\frac{1}{2n}\Big)^n\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big(1-\frac{1}{3n}\big)\Big)^n$$

Can you finish from this?

Comment: Can I calculate the limit of each of the factors to arrive at the final result?

Comment: Yes... recall that for any sequence $c_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}c\in\mathbb{C}$, $\lim_n\Big(1+\frac{c_n}{n}\Big)^n=e^c$.